# Remove Gap label and value highcharts

Tags: highcharts

In this `HighCharts` example, how do I remove the gap between when all value is zero

http://jsfiddle.net/qo02Lk55/

I want to put all value in yAxis like this picture
[image]

Comment: You can define the max and tickInterval as 1. http://jsfiddle.net/oueu9gvy/

Comment: is it posible remove line on the right?

Comment: Yes, set gridLineWidth as 0. Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nrsesm3w/